# Почему не стартует MariaDB?

Tags: linux, mariadb

Работал с MySQL и все прекрасно работало.
После удаления, установки и последующей настройки MariaDB сервис не может запуститься.

```
ruslan@user-All-Series:~$ sudo systemctl start mariadb
Job for mariadb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

проверка статуса:

```
ruslan@user-All-Series:~$ sudo systemctl status mariadb



  ● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.1.34 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2018-08-27 15:46:43 MSK; 10min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 22712 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 22624 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 22615 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 22604 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 22712 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

авг 27 15:45:10 user-All-Series systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.1.34 database server...
авг 27 15:45:11 user-All-Series mysqld[22712]: 2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 22712 ...
авг 27 15:46:41 user-All-Series systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.                                                                                                                                        
авг 27 15:46:43 user-All-Series systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.                                                                                                                                                  
авг 27 15:46:43 user-All-Series systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.1.34 database server.
```

попытка входа

```
ruslan@user-All-Series:~$ sudo mariadb
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory"
```

)

error.log

```
2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.39-83.1 started; log sequence number 1616797
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803030976256 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
    2018-08-27 15:45:11 139803697032320 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
    Version: '10.1.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Ubuntu 18.04
    2018-08-27 15:46:41 139803696502528 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown
    2018-08-27 15:46:41 139803696502528 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
    2018-08-27 15:46:41 139803089671936 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
    2018-08-27 15:46:41 139803696502528 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
    2018-08-27 15:46:42 139803696502528 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
    2018-08-27 15:46:43 139803696502528 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1616807
    2018-08-27 15:46:43 139803696502528 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Ну если после установки он запустился для настройки, а после неё не запускается - видать, как-то не так настроил... Для более осмысленного предположения одной записи "mariadb.service: Start operation timed out." маловато будет. Да и некоторые предыдущие строки лога как-то обрезаны не по делу.

Comment: @Akina, настройка проводилась командой mysql_secure_installation и не более. строки обрезаны из-за ширины терминала. какие еще команды попробовать?

Comment: @Akina , при этом некоторое время после старта (1-2 мин) сервис работает,  им ожно взаимодействовать с субд, но после сервис самопроизвольно выключается и приходится его снова запускать.

Comment: *некоторое время после старта (1-2 мин) сервис работает, им ожно взаимодействовать с субд, но после сервис самопроизвольно выключается* См. [логи Маши](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/overview-of-mariadb-logs/). Она без логирования не выключится, если только не наглухо зависла (что вряд ли).

Comment: @Akina , посмотрите. я добавил еррор лог, не совсем понимаю в чем ошибка.

Comment: еще я подпрваил результат вызова статуса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем понадобилось всего лишь сделать `systemctl enable mariadb` и перезагрузить компьютер, как бы банально и глупо это не звучало.

Comment: Ответы-ссылки не приветствуются на Stack Overflow, даже если ссылка на другой Stack Overflow; опишите кратко текстом, что такое «вот так»